# Pass a php function instead of a file to jquery $post method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i started to learn jquery yesterday so i'm not so good.

I've a question:

as title there's a way to pass a php function instead of a file to jquery $.post method?

Here's an example of what i would to do:

```
function send(str)
{
    $.post
    ( 
        "<?php PHPfunction(); ?>",
        {send:str},  
        function(data)
        {
           $("#output-text").html(data.reply);
        },
           "json"
    );
}
```

there's a way to do that? or i need always to pass a file to the first parameter?

Just another question:

how can i pass more than 1 row from php to jquery in the ajax reply?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use AJAX to make a request for that function.  For more information, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.  Google can also provide you a ton of examples because what you're asking is a fairly common problem with plenty of good solutions.

Comment: $.post isn't the issue, it's how you are using it that is. Take a look at the doc's Mark linked, you'll see how it's meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is run on the server before the page is fully loaded, so you can't call a PHP function on the fly like that. Javascript runs within the browser afterwards, on the clients machine. They are two separate environments, code wise.

You're better off calling a page that uses the function, using Ajax or something.